# Get latitude/longitude coordinates from a Google map using a marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just wondered if anyone knew of a simple script available that will do the following:

Load a google map in view, when clicked it displays a marker that will save the lat and long values to a variable?

Does anyone know if something like this already exists in PHP?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something similar to this [Latitude-Longitude Finder Tool](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/03/latitude-longitude-finder-tool.html). The example code <del>is</del> was API v2. Below is trimmed down version of the code using Google Maps API v3:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4975941, -0.0803232);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
    draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
    console.log(a);
    // bingo!
    // a.latLng contains the co-ordinates where the marker was dropped
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ZW9jP/4/)

Explanation: you must set the [`draggable`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) property of the marker to true. You can then hook a callback function to that marker's `dragend` event; the new co-ordinates are passed to the function and you can assign them to a JavaScript variable or form field.

Comment: I've almost cracked it - I cannot get the lat/lng values out of the object, but can see the values in console log... it is getting there?
http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9jP/6/

Comment: awesome Salman! You the man!! :)
Your code works perfectly!
I've adjusted slightly to incorporate some jQuery, thanks for your effort it is really appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

```
// add a click event handler to the map object
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latLng)
    {
        // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
        document.getElementById("latFld").value = latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById("lngFld").value = latLng.lng();
    });
```

I thinks when you will get the lat-lng then you can place marker.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Google maps API v.3. From the [events page](http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   // use event.latLng to place a google.maps.Marker
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I have managed the following so far - how could I amend this to move the marker position when I click anywhere on the map

http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9jP/

I've added the following but it doesnt seem to do anything

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  addMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

the below code works well

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4975941, -0.0803232);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
```