# Google map API in my web application

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

In one of my web appliation there is a form for entering shop details including its latitude and longitude.

I need to implement a Google Map in my application through which if an user click on Map of particular point then I have to fill my latitude and longitude text fields with user clicked place's lat and long.

Is there is any way for doing that ? 
Pelase help

Comment: Yes, there's plenty of ways of doing that. Are you having trouble? There's plenty of documentation and examples on the Google Maps API site.

Comment: What you tried?can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks guys .. I am new to this . and if you don't mind please suggest / refer me a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Onclick on map get lat lng](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9000813/1035257)

[Gmap tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial)

[gmap help ful tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html)

These link will help you you sure . check it out.