# Javascript to PHP and innerHTML deletion

Tags: javascript, php

I am implementing a script but need some help on two issues that I am unable to figure out.  The idea is to allow someone to create a running route and store the route into a database via the coordinates.

The code is as follows:
(credits to: [Post 19 Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000813/get-latitude-longitude-coordinates-from-a-google-map-using-a-marker) and [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ZW9jP/4/) here)

```
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Drawing Tools (B)</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4975941, -0.0803232);
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: latlng,
                    zoom: 11,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
                    draggable: true
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
                    console.log(a);
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
                    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
                });
            };
            </script>
              </head>
              <body>
            <div id="map" style="height:300px;"></div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

**First problem I am trying to solve:**

```
div.innerHTML = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
```

How can I add each of these lat & long coordinates (as the person creates their route) into a PHP array in order to insert them into a database.  I am struggling with this as it is displaying them on the fly.

**Second problem I am trying to solve:**

```
div.innerHTML = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
```

If the user drops the pin is there a way to delete the latest coords should they make a mistake?

I have tried different methods (I am no good with JS);

```
div.innerHTML = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4) + ', <a onClick="$(this).closest("div").remove();">Delete</a>';
```

But can't seem to get it working.

Any help on these problems would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Your remove link is using jquery. Do you have jquery included on the page, because i see no other mention of it.

Comment: Thank you Steve! How did I miss that?  Yes that fixed Problem 2! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to hold the co-ordinates in a javascript object/array so they can be added/removed and saved easily.

I would also use a more appropriate html element to display them to the user, eg an unordered/ordered list:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Drawing Tools (B)</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            //Create an object to hold the values and encapsulate adding, removing and saving
            function List(ul, save){
                this.items = [];
                this.ul = ul;
                this.save = save;
            }
            //add item to list
            List.prototype.add=function(item){
                this.items.push(item);
                this.rebuildDom();
            };
            //remove item from list
            List.prototype.removeAt=function(index){
                this.items.splice(index, 1);
                this.rebuildDom();
            };
            //update the contents of the <ul> list to display current list items
            List.prototype.rebuildDom=function(){
                var html='';
                for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
                    //note change here, each item is now an array, so it must be
                    //joined into a string for display
                    html += '<li>'+this.items[i].join(' , ') +'<span class="remove" data-id="'+i+'">X</span></li>'
                }
                $('#'+this.ul).html(html);
            };
            //upload the data via ajax
            List.prototype.upload=function(){
                var data = {data: this.items};
                $.post('/save.php', data, function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                })
            };
            List.prototype.init = function(){
                var _this = this;
                //remove items from list when remove is clicked
                $('#'+this.ul).on('click', 'span.remove', function(){
                    var index = $(this).data('id');
                    _this.removeAt(index);
                });
                //bind to click event of save button, and upload data
                $('#'+this.save).click(function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    _this.upload();
                });
            };

            var list = new List('items', 'save');
            list.init();


            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4975941, -0.0803232);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
                console.log(a);
                //note item is now an array containing both values, not a string
                var item = [a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) ,  a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4)];
                //add item to our list
                list.add(item);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        body{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        #map{
            height: 400px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        h3{
            font-family: inherit;
        }
        #items{
            list-style: none;
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        }
        #items li{
            background-color: #666666;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            color:#ffffff;
        }
        #items li span.remove{
            float: right;
            background-color: red;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: -5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" ></div>

<button id="save">Save</button>

<h3>Co-ordinates of your route:</h3>

<ul id="items"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rmsjf5oy/2/

To retrieve the data in php, you can simply access the `$_POST` super global:

```
//save.php

if(isset($_POST['data']){
    $co-ordinates = $_POST['data'];

    // $co-ordinates is now a php array like
    //   [
    //        ['51.4886', '-0.0666'],
    //        ['51.4886', '-0.0666'],
    //        ['51.4886', '-0.0666']
    //   ]

    //do something with the data then send a message back to the javascript

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['success'=>true, 'message'=>'Thanks, got the data']);
}
```

Look in the js console in your browser to see the response, or do something other than `console.log(response);` in the `upload` method to do something else with the data, such as show it in a div

Comment: Steve that is awesome, thank you. I will use this. Would you know how I can get the lat & long values into PHP after the save is clicked?

Comment: @NOJ75 Sure, i'll update my answer. I have changed the js a little to make the data easier to deal with

Comment: Legend! Thank you @Steve. That is extremely useful to me. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @NOJ75 No problem, glad i could help

Comment: Hi Steve, I have been playing around with this and it is working great.  I am tring to take it one step further by adding a Polyline as the user plots the coords but the lines are not working.  Would you know how to implement this into your code?

Answer (score 0):

### First problem

You can't send JS data to PHP unless you make a server call. Once the page is rendered - PHP shuts down and that's it, while JS keeps running in the browser (read about server-side vs client-side programming).

You probably want to make an AJAX call to send the lat/long data back to the server in order to insert them into the database.

---

### Second problem

(please try to have a separate question for each next time)

`$(this).parent().remove();` should work.

Comment: Roger on the separate questions. Apologies for that. $(this).parent().remove(); did not work unfortunately.

Comment: No problem about the question. Hmmm, it should work - can you paste an example div content here (or in the question body)?

Comment: It was because I did not include JQuery!  Just need to solve the first problem now.  Thank you Shornz.

Comment: Ahhh, now that makes sense. :)  You're welcome, good luck with that AJAX stuff.